# File in Database is only 1 slash instead of double slash

Tags: java, database, filepath

can someone give me a proper explanation why in java (or is this applicable to all programming language?) if the path is retrieved from the database, it is okay to use only 1 slash like '\192.168.173.220\folder\folder1\folder2' instead of '\\192.168.173.220\folder\folder1\folder2'.

Comment: You need to give more information on this. What you are storing the DB is a string? How do add the path to the DB? How do you retrieve it? When is the second slash there, when is it gone?

Answer (score 2):

When you write a String *literal* in Java *source code*, you need to escape backslash characters.

But in a String *object* ... which is what you get at runtime when you read a String from a database (or anywhere else) ... each character stands for itself.